# How to order by pivot table data in Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my Database, I have:

- `tops` Table
- `posts` Table
- `tops_has_posts` Table.

When I retrieve a top on my `tops` table I also retrieve the `posts` about the top.
But what if I want to retrieve these posts in a certain order?
So I added a `range` field in my pivot table `tops_has_posts` and I tried to order by the result using Eloquent but it didn't work.

I try this :

```
$top->articles()->whereHas('articles', function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('range', 'ASC');
})->get()->toArray();
```

And this :

```
$top->articles()->orderBy('range', 'ASC')->get()->toArray();
```

Both were desperate attempts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For **Laravel 8.17.2+** you can use `::orderByPivot()`.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.17.2

Comment: Thx for the hint, unfortunate it's not in the docu yet...

Comment: Lol you champ! L9 still doesn't have this in the docs : https://github.com/laravel/docs/search?q=orderByPivot

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation? Is it still buggy as of the moment? This was released nearly 2 years ago.

Comment: @Shulz works like a charm, I don't know why it's still not documented

Answer (score 47):

There are 2 ways - one with specifying the `table.field`, other using Eloquent alias `pivot_field` if you use `withPivot('field')`:

```
// if you use withPivot
public function articles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Article', 'tops_has_posts')->withPivot('range');
}

// then: (with not whereHas)
$top = Top::with(['articles' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('pivot_range', 'asc');
}])->first(); // or get() or whatever
```

This will work, because Eloquent aliases all fields provided in `withPivot` as `pivot_field_name`.

Now, generic solution:

```
$top = Top::with(['articles' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('tops_has_posts.range', 'asc');
}])->first(); // or get() or whatever

// or:
$top = Top::first();
$articles = $top->articles()->orderBy('tops_has_posts.range', 'asc')->get();
```

This will order the related query.

**Note:** Don't make your life hard with naming things this way. `posts` are not necessarily `articles`, I would use either one or the other name, unless there is really need for this.

Answer (score 26):

In Laravel 5.6+ (not sure about older versions) it's convenient to use this:

```
public function articles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Article', 'tops_has_posts')->withPivot('range')->orderBy('tops_has_posts.range');
}
```

In this case, whenever you will call `articles`, they will be sorted automaticaly by `range` property.

Answer (score 19):

In Laravel **5.4** I have the following relation that works fine in `Set` model which `belongsToMany` of `Job` model:

```php
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class, 'eqtype_jobs')
        ->withPivot(['created_at','updated_at','id'])
        ->orderBy('pivot_created_at','desc');
}
```

The above relation returns all `jobs` that the specified `Set` has been joined ordered by the pivot table's (`eqtype_jobs`) field `created_at` DESC.

The SQL printout of `$set->jobs()->paginate(20)` Looks like the following:

```sql
select
  `jobs`.*, `eqtype_jobs`.`set_id` as `pivot_set_id`,
  `eqtype_jobs`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id`,
  `eqtype_jobs`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
  `eqtype_jobs`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`,
  `eqtype_jobs`.`id` as `pivot_id`
from `jobs`
inner join `eqtype_jobs` on `jobs`.`id` = `eqtype_jobs`.`job_id`
where `eqtype_jobs`.`set_id` = 56
order by `pivot_created_at` desc
limit 20
offset 0
```

Comment: This ->orderBy('pivot_created_at','desc'); worked for me . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

in your blade try this:

```
$top->articles()->orderBy('pivot_range','asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you print out the SQL query of `belongsToMany` relationship, you will find that the column names of pivot tables are using the `pivot_` prefix as a new alias.

For example, `created_at`, `updated_at` in pivot table have got `pivot_created_at`, `pivot_updated_at` aliases. So the `orderBy` method should use these aliases instead.

Here is an example of how you can do that.

```
class User {
    ...
    public function posts(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
                   Post::class, 
                   'post_user', 
                   'user_id', 
                   'post_id')
               ->withTimestamps()
               ->latest('pivot_created_at');
    }
    ...
}
```

You can use `orderBy` instead of using `latest` method if you prefer. In the above example, `post_user` is pivot table, and you can see that the column name for ordering is now `pivot_created_at` or `pivot_updated_at`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    public function keywords() {
    return $this->morphToMany(\App\Models\Keyword::class, "keywordable")->withPivot('order');
}
public function getKeywordOrderAttribute() {
    return $this->keywords()->first()->pivot->order;
}
```

and append keyword attribiute to model after geting and use sortby

```
$courses->get()->append('keyword_order')->sortBy('keyword_order');
```