# many-to-many relationship: order by on pivot table not working

Tags: many-to-many, sql-order-by, laravel-6

I have these relationship between `school` and `associate` models:

```
// School model
public function associates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Associate', 'school_associate', 'school_id', 'associate_id')
        ->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date');
}

// Associate model
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('School', 'school_associate', 'associate_id', 'school_id')
        ->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date');
}
```

I need to get all associates of one school ordered by start_date.

This is what I tried without success (in this try I am searching in all schools):

```
dd(\App\Associate::with(['schools' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('pivot_start_date', 'desc');
}])->toSql());
```

And I get this sql (notice no `order by` clause):

```
select * from `associate`
```

I tried to edit the relationship like this:

```
// Associate model
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('School', 'school_associate', 'associate_id', 'school_id')
        ->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date')
        ->orderBy('pivot_start_date', 'desc'); // also tried without "pivot_"
}
```

And according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551078/how-to-order-by-pivot-table-data-in-laravels-eloquent-orm), I also tried :

```
// Associate model
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('School', 'school_associate', 'associate_id', 'school_id')
        ->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date')
        ->orderBy('school_associate.start_date', 'desc');
}
```

But I always get the same query and the results are not ordered.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983973/9193055) solution should work for you.

Comment: @Remul I tried without success

Comment: Could you add it to the question so I can take a look at it, maybe there is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using query builder in this way.
This function is in `Associate` model:

```
public function scopeLast($query, $school_ids = [])
{
    $query->join('school_associate', "{$this->table}.{$this->primaryKey}", '=', 'school_associate.associate_id')
        ->join('school', 'school.school_id', '=', 'school_associate.school_id')
        ->whereIn('school.school_id', $school_ids)
        ->orderBy('school_associate.start_date', 'desc');

    return $query;
}
```