# Laravel Eloquent WhereHas with ORDER column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a whereHas query which gets data from a pivot table. But on the pivot table i also have a extra column called 'order' and i use this column to make sure the items are ordered in the correct SEQUENCE as it represents a bus route. Ex: Bus/Ferry stops at 1 2 3 4 5 6.

We have a departure and destination point which are represented as 'port_id'.

So for example the below query gives me the correct data but i need to make sure that the 'order' column is always in the correct sequence based on the departure port id and the arrival port id. So if you would search for port_id 14 to port_id 15 it should not return any results as the 'order' column is not connecting those in that way.

This is what i've tried:

```
        $routes = Route::whereHas('ports', function($query) use ($request) {
       $query->where('port_id', $request->route['from']['id']);
    })
    ->whereHas('ports', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('port_id', $request->route['to']['id']);
    })->get();
```

And this is the pivot table:
[image]

This is the route table:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: could you provide table structure + sample data + expected result separately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order by pivot table data in Laravel's Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551078/how-to-order-by-pivot-table-data-in-laravels-eloquent-orm)

Comment: @Tpojka No, it doesnt, thanks.

Comment: Help me understand it better. It is possible for request to be: `route_id == 3`, `departurePort == 14`, `destinationPort == 16` where you would like result of `[14, 17, 16]`; is this correct anticipation?

Comment: @Tpojka The query needs to check that the 'order' column is in SEQUENCE of the route. For example, a bus departs from point A to point E and in between it stops at B, C and D. This stops are in sequence, same like 1 2 3 4. The 'order' column is used to manage the sequence of the stops of a specific journey. So is someone wants to from point B to C the query needs to also check the if the 'order' column is the correct sequence for the bus/ferry route.

Comment: @Tpojka So basicly it needs to check if the 'order' column of the departure port id is lower than the 'order' column of the destination port id and the destination port id needs to be ofcourse higher to the column 'order' of departure port.

Comment: @Tpojka I can actually get the desired results but i don't want to make extra loops with php, i just want it all in one mysql query.

Comment: So my assumption from previous comment is exactly correct? Yes or no?

Comment: @Tpojka yes, as long as the result is based on the correct sequence by the 'order' table.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am just following example from question and asking you additional questions to make better stands for my anticipation of problem. Do you find useful if you set `->groupBy('route_id')->get()` at the end instead?

Comment: @Tpojka No because this will just group it, i need the query do an actual check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215019/discussion-between-tpojka-and-adriaan).

Answer (score 1):

i think you could make ordering using join, then ordering the result
by route_id then by 'order' column:

```
$routes = Route::whereHas('ports', function($query) use ($request) {
       $query->where('port_id', $request->route['from']['id']);
    })
    ->whereHas('ports', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('port_id', $request->route['to']['id']);
    })
->join('route_port','route_port.route_id','=','routes.id')
->join('ports','route_port.port_id','ports.id')->orderby('route_id')
->orderby('order')->get();
```

please correct the table names if they were wrong ...

Comment: Thanks but what i need is to get only the routes where the ports are in sequence of the departure and destination port id.

So for example if i have a port_id 5 as departure and a port_id 8 as a arrival port. I need to get only the routes where these ports are in SEQUENCE of each other. Thanks